# Is is possible to convert opus-fltp to opus-s16 (or) decode opus-fltp to pcm using opus API

Tags: html, audio, audio-recording, opus, web-mediarecorder

I need to convert the opus-audio taken from MediaRecorder API to pcm. Audio captured from API is in ***fltp*** type, I need to convert that to ***pcm-fltp*** or ***pcm-s16***.

I am aware of opus_decode() function in opus, but for that we need to pass ***opus_s16*** as far as I know. Is it possible to convert ***opus-fltp*** to ***opus-s16*** or Is there any other way to decode ***opus-fltp*** to ***pcm*** ?

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks to Kiran. For that, we meed to parse ogg header to get audio segment, and then decode audio segment into pcm using opus library.

Answer (score 0):

Would this WASM [opus-stream-decoder](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder) help you?  This decoder uses `libopusfile` which should accept any valid Ogg Opus format and decode to stereo floating point PCM.